# apache2 sites-enabled order, specify subdomains/domains configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, domains

I will start with describing what I want to achieve.

First of all I have one main domain which is **xxx.pl**, a domain has 4 subdomains **000.xxx.pl**, **111.xxx.pl**, **222.xxx.pl**, **333.xxx.pl**. Also I have another domain **yyy.pl** with its own subdomains (mostly the same). Of course it will be more domains, but its not the point.

Now what I need is any domain which doesn't have its vhost set up for http, will point **/var/www/pl.xxx** and the same with https. (so its the default site) which for now I have set up as (and similar for https):

***sites-enabled/999-default***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@xxx.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/pl.xxx
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/pl.xxx>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So this file as far as I understand will be loaded as last so apache will go there if there was no more precise answer.

Then there is file for main domain (HTTP and HTTPS is the same except the keys etc.) which will be loaded before default site config.

***sites-enabled/998-pl.xxx***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@xxx.pl
    ServerName xxx.pl
    ServerAlias *.xxx.pl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/pl.xxx
    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/pl.xxx>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And now I need to specify 2 domains (only on https), on http they should use **sites-enabled/998-pl.xxx** config.

***sites-enabled/997-pl.xxx.000***

ServerAdmin postmaster@xxx.pl

```
    ServerName 000.xxx.pl
    ServerAlias 000.xxx.pl

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/pl.xxx.000

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/pl.xxx.000>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

And all would be good except the other domain **yyy.pl** on the https use the same config as the **000.xxx.pl** address. And what I need it to restrict only **000.xxx.pl** to use this address. Not all other not assigned domains.

so **https://yyy.pl** | **https://000.yyy.pl** etc. should use **default-ssl** settings instead of **000.xxx.pl** settings.

Please help me understand whats going on. Maybe I misunderstood the apache config usage.

Edit:

Generally the problem is partially solved, because it works. but there is one interesting thing about dependency /etc/hosts entry with the subdomain configuration.

Comment: You want "any domain which doesn't have its vhost set up for http, will point /var/www/pl.xxx" but in 999-default you have `DocumentRoot /var/www/default`. It seems something is wrong here... Please improve your answer so it is more clear. Try to disable all vhosts which are not important for solving this issue and then paste content of all configuration files from sites-enabled.

Comment: its just a typo, maybe Its not clear enough, so I will try to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sites-enabled/999-default
>
> [...]
>
> So this file as far as I understand will be loaded as last so apache will go there if there was no more precise answer.

This works the other way around. So the site to be shown as default should be the **first** one Apache have to parse. I would name it 000-default or whatever which will go **before** the others.

Comment: So I have to have something else wrong then, because if I moved default to be the first, my 000.xxx.pl domain is using a default setting then.

Comment: OK I found out that it didn't work because my subdomain (000.xxx.pl) was in /etc/hosts as **000.xxx.pl 000** if I removed it it works good. But will this affect my mail server? As I set up this address as **myhostname **

Comment: well still your answer was correct, because apparently the default should be first.